# Materialize and Datetime Picker Interact with Each Other

Tags: html, css, materialize, datetimepicker

I have a Materialize and Datetime picker in my project. The problem is that the Materialize library denoted as  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">` is interacting with the Datetime picker. When I open to select the date and time, the portion that allows for the selecting of time is missing but appears when the Materialize library is removed. Also, I cannot figure out how to keep the Datetime picker in its place when the user scrolls the page.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SB Admin 2 - Tables</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="css/couponsexample.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="buttonTest" id="myBtn">New Discount</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="msform">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" name="datetimes" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <script src="couponsjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not real familiar with Materialize, but just looking through the css in the inspector, it looks like the select element has its display set to none by some setting in the materialize css.  If you add something like

```
.daterangepicker select {

  display:inline-block;
}
```

to your css, that might take care of that problem.  I edited the Snippet to see if that actually works in your example.  I am not quite clear yet on what the other issue is, but I am sure it probably has something to do with the CSS and you might be able to override that depending upon what you want it to do.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.daterangepicker select {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SB Admin 2 - Tables</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="css/couponsexample.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="buttonTest" id="myBtn">New Discount</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="msform">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" name="datetimes" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <script src="couponsjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you change the .modal position from fixed to absolute it will scroll with the window, although those are usually fixed.

Comment: NICE!! thank you so much that worked. I was stuck on this for the entire day

Comment: You might want to make sure that doesn't break something else, but probably not since it just affects the selects in the daterangepicker.

Comment: Actually, making it "absolute" solved the scrolling issue but makes the modal back drop cover only partially the entire page; im wondering if the absolute goes to the nearest object and causes that problem